# Asynchronous JavaScript and object permanence

Tags: javascript, oop, asynchronous, coding-style

I have JS code roughly like this:

```
function myObject()
{
    this.a = 13;

    this.fetchData = function()
    {
        alert(this.a);
        getData(this.processData);
    }

    this.processData = function(data)
    {
        // do stuff with data
        alert(this.a);
    }

    this.fetchData();
}

function getData(callback)
{
    // do async request for data and call callback with the result
}
```

My problem is: The function *fetchData* has access to my *a* variable via the *this* keyword, but the other function *processData* does not when called by *getData*. I understand why this happens, but don't know how to work around it.

How would you approach this problem preferably in OOP style? (The function *getData* has to be available to multiple classes)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two options:

1) Have `getData` accept a context parameter (usually called `context` or `thisArg`) and use `callback.apply(context, ...)` or `callback.call(context, ...)` to call it. So:

```
function getData(callback, context) {
    // ...when it's time to call it:
    callback.call(context, arg1, arg2);
    // or
    callback.apply(context, [arg1, arg2]);
}
```

2) Create a function that, when called, will turn around and call the original callback with `this` set to the correct value. (This is sometimes called "binding".)

For example, using an explicit closure:

```
this.fetchData = function()
{
    var self = this;

    alert(this.a);
    getData(getDataCallback);

    function getDataCallback(arg1, arg2) {
        self.processData(arg1, arg2);
    }
}
```

Or have a generic `bind` function to do it (which will also involve a closure, but in a nice controlled context so it's not closing over stuff you don't need). See link below for an example of a simple `bind` function.

More: [*You must remember `this`*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/04/you-must-remember-this.html)

Comment: +1: for option 2, you would call getData(function(){ this.processData(); }); instead of getData(thisProcessData);

Comment: @Eric: No, that won't work. `this` is defined *entirely* by how a function is called, not where it's defined. Your `getData(function(){ this.processData(); });` would have exactly the same problem as `getData(this.processData);` You can, though, use a closure (I've added a closure example).

Comment: @T.J. Crowder: of course, you're right. Thanks for adding the example.

Comment: BTW: does jQuery have a built-in binding function for doing this?

Answer (score 1):

I think that you only need to define "a" as a local variable so that it is in the cope of both fetchData and getData, something like this:

```
function myObject() {
   var a = 13;

   this.fetchData = function() {
      alert(a);
      getData(this.processData);
   }

   this.processData = function(data) {
      // do stuff with data
      alert(a);
   }

   this.fetchData();
}
```

You could also do,

```
function myObject() {
   this.a = 13;
   var that = this;

   this.fetchData = function() {
      alert(that.a);
      getData(this.processData);
   }

   this.processData = function(data) {
      // do stuff with data
      alert(that.a);
   }

   this.fetchData();
}
```

Comment: +1 for setting a in private scope of closures fetchData and processData.